# Restricting access to Android libarary

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, bintray, jcenter

I created Android library that will be used as library for different project like Http library which contains functionality related to Http communication. 
I know i need to upload the .aar(Android Archieve) file to jcentre repo so i used bintray.com and  [used this to create aar and upload to bintray server](http://blog.bintray.com/2014/02/11/bintray-as-pain-free-gateway-to-maven-central/)

The issue i am facing that how i can restrict the access of library i.e library can be accessed by valid credentials.

Comment: Do not put the library on a public server (e.g., JCenter). Put the library on your own server, and only allow those with "valid credentials" to work with your server.

Answer (score 2):

Bintray has very sophisticated entitlements model, which allows you to control who can see and download your package. You can rely on Bintray's user management, use your own (or 3rd party) user management, or generate obscure (secret) URLs, optionally limiting them by expiry time or number of downloads.

Please see Bintray documentation for details on how to limit your package access and [generate entitlement links](https://bintray.com/docs/usermanual/premium/premium_externalaccess.html).